# TMUX and terminal colors are not the same locally and over ssh

Tags: tmux, colors, fish, kitty

I have a bunch of dotfiles that allow me to have a pretty theme on my terminal and tmux on my local host. I use kitty, fish and tmux. To properly define colors and have a global coherence, I use the following files :

- .Xresoures
- kitty.conf
- fish_prompt.fish
- .tmux.conf

On my local host, everything looks really clean :
[image]

I also have a remote server, which runs the same arch + fish + tmux and uses exactly the same dotfiles. However, when SSH-ing into the server, everything looks completely different :

[image]

I have google around and there are a lot of tutorials that tell you to add a bunch of weird configs, but none actually explain what is really happening under the hood (also, as you can see, none of them worked).

Here is what I tried to do to make it work (without really understanding why) :

- Added to tmux.conf :

```
set^[[3m -g default-terminal "xterm-kitty"
set-option^[[3m -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-kitty*:Tc"
```

- Added the xterm-kitty terminfo file
- Change the `TERM` env variable to xterm-kitty on login

I would love for some resources to point to how this all works! Thanks!

Edit :

For clarity, here are the values of `TERM` I have :

- On local host : `xterm-kitty`
- On local host inside tmux : `xterm-256color`
- On remote host directly after opening ssh : `xterm-kitty`
- On remote host in tmux : `xterm-256color`

All files are synced using a git repo, all versions are identical. I have transfered the same `terminfo` file related to `xterm-kitty` on both hosts. Also, using [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnMorales/dotfiles/master/colors/24-bit-color.sh) script, I can see that all colors are properly displayed and identical on both hosts.

I also noticed that logging into the remote machine without tmux yields yet another combination of colors (same fish config file used everywhere) :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it! It was a combination of all the answers given, with one important extra variable.

Required steps :

- Ensuring the `TERM` variables used are the same on every host and inside every tmux (I ended up using `xterm-kitty` on the hosts directly and `tlux-256color` inside the TMUX sessions). [Thanks to Nicholas Marriott](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/579165/405306).
- add `Tc;` to the infocmp of the terminals I use, using [this snippet provided by Thomas Dickey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/579272/405306) :

```
infocmp -x tmux-256color >foo
printf '\tTc,\n' >>foo
tic -x foo
```

- Add `set -g fish_term24bit 1` to my config.fish in order to force fish to use trucolor mode.

Answer (score 4):

`default-terminal` sets the default `TERM` inside tmux. Do not set this to `xterm-kitty` - tmux is not xterm, or kitty. Set it to `tmux-256color` if it exists on your computer (check `infocmp tmux-256color`), otherwise `screen-256color`.

Similarly, do not set `TERM` in shell profiles to the same thing for all terminals.

The `terminal-overrides` line you have tells tmux that when it sees `TERM` set to `xterm-kitty` it means the terminal supports true (RGB) colour (hence `Tc`).

`TERM` inside tmux tells programs inside tmux what they are talking to (tmux). `TERM` outside tmux tells tmux what it is talking to (in this case, kitty).

If it works locally but not over ssh then the most likely things are:

- Different `TERM` outside tmux. Are you sure `echo $TERM` shows the same immediately before you start tmux on both your local computer and over ssh?
- The tmux configs are not actually the same, are you sure they are? If you need `terminal-overrides` in one place you will need it in the other, if not then you won't.
- Are you sure `xterm-kitty` exists on both computers and is the same? Check `infocmp xterm-kitty`.
- Different tmux versions. Are you sure they are the same? Check `tmux -V`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added a bunch of clarifications to the question to cover for your questions. I do understand the problem a little better now, thanks!

Comment: If it is different without tmux, I would focus on that first - the only things at fault in that case could be kitty, fish or the `xterm-kitty` terminfo file you have installed. Is it also different if you use another terminal like xterm or gnome-terminal? Are you sure there is no default fish config that is interfering?

Comment: Using xterm locally without tmux yields results that are identical to using tmux on the remote SSH host. I'll continue messing with different settings to see if I can make it work. Thanks!

Comment: There is no `xterm-kitty` in vanilla terminfo.  The correct rendered-upon terminal type is, assuming that this is KiTTY rather than kitty, probably [`putty-256color`](https://www.invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty-256color).

Comment: No, this is about [kitty the terminal emulator](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/). This one has its own terminfo.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using tmux on the local-machine, then running ssh to the remote machine, there's no way that the remote session can tell that you're able to use RGB colors instead-of (or in addition to) indexed (256-colors).  That's because the tmux "Tc" override is not visible to the remote session.

You can work around this by modifying the terminal description which corresponds to the *default-terminal* setting of tmux, e.g., by adding whatever settings you use with *terminal-overrides* to the text-file for the terminal description, and using **`tic`** to compile it (on each machine).  For example (if the *default-terminal* is **`tmux`**):

```
infocmp -x tmux >foo
printf '\tTc,\n' >>foo
tic -x foo
```

Kitty has an [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20200327012958/https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/faq.html), but it overlooks "-x" for [**`infocmp`**.](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html)

There are a couple of remaining points to consider:

- Copying the binary files created by **`tic`** is unreliable (for more than one reason).
- If the same terminal description is available on the remote side, you'll get (more) consistent behavior, assuming that the remote application uses the terminal description **content** rather than the [**name**](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2018-09/msg00013.html) of the terminal description.